# Posting data via js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really new to Javascript and its many brilliant libraries, I find even the most simple scripts hard to perform.

I do want to learn this language, because it would be powerful for creating client websites, however at the moment I am trying to do something relatively simple, this is to flag a personal message on my site. There are many messages in a big list, and what I am looking at doing is when the user clicks the "Flag PM" image, it will run flag.php in the background which will change the flag field in MySQL from 0 to 1.

This script is all dependant on one field, that is id so I can run this through the database. Anyway, here is my code;

**flag.php**

```
 require('_inc/_core/core.php'); // inc core_funcs for sql & clean
$pm_id = clean($_POST['p_id']); // create new variable, clean the post
echo "The ID for the PM is " . $pm_id;
mysql_query("UPDATE `messages` SET `flag_status` = 1 WHERE `id` = {$pm_id}"); // update the db
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
     // Flag a Personal Message
$("#flagPM").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.post("flag.php", { p_id: pm_id } );
    alert(event);
});
```

**HTML handling the form**

```
<form action="#" id="flagPM"><input type="hidden" id="pm_id" value="$id" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="FLAG" /></form>
```

So there is a hidden input field named **pm_id** that contains what I want posted.

Would really appreciate some help, the Javascript is being run from an independent file that is two directory's up from flag.php

Thank you

Comment: So what is the question? PS: you send `$.post()` and process `$_GET`. Looks inconsistent

Comment: you are using POST method to post the data and then using $_GET to get it. It should be there in $_POST['id']. Also in your javascript you have not assigned any value to your id variable. You need to fill it with the value you need

Comment: Sorry that is not even the correct file, I am updating it with the correct code sorry about that!

Comment: can you also post the html code which contains the id element?

Comment: You send it as `{id: id}`, and retrieve it like `$_POST['p_id']`. It seems to me that that won't  work...

Comment: @MukeshSoni this has now been corrected, thanks. 

11684 corrected that issue, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

> the Javascript is being run from an independent file that is two
>   directory's up from flag.php

In that case simply doing:

```
$.post("flag.php", { id: id } );
```

wont reach the `flag.php` file, you need to specify correct path including folder names that you mentioned:

```
$.post("folder1/folder2/flag.php", { id: id } );
```

By the way, you should use a callback for the `$.post` function to know what message is returned by `flag.php`:

```
$.post("flag.php", { id: id }, function(data){
  alert(data);
} );
```

From your `flag.php`, make sure to `echo` something so that you get that response in your ajax handler:

```
// your other code here, such as query, etc
echo 'whatever...';
```

Comment: I have just updated my post with most of what you have said, when I click the button I do not get a alert window containing the data, which means it is not running the javascript?

Comment: @Jake Ball: it means that programming is something more than just copy and paste

Comment: Well could you link me to the appropriate documentation because I am in the deep-end here, I have never done much js/jquery in my time so I have no idea what can be achieved and how it can be achieved, as I outlined in my OP.